# How to get checkboxes values in OnPostAsync() .Net Core Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I have these three model - Scaffold-ed from the database

```
    public Course()
    {
    CourseProjectType = new HashSet<CourseProjectType>();
    Student = new HashSet<Student>();
    }

    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CourseProjectType> CourseProjectType { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Student { get; set; }
```

---

```
public ProjectType()
    {
        CourseProjectType = new HashSet<CourseProjectType>();
        Project = new HashSet<Project>();
    }

    public int ProjectTypeId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectTypeName { get; set; }
    public string ProjectTypePrefix { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public bool checkboxAnswer { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CourseProjectType> CourseProjectType { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Project> Project { get; set; }
```

---

```
public partial class CourseProjectType
{
    public int ProjectTypeId { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }

    public Course Course { get; set; }
    public ProjectType ProjectType { get; set; }
}
```

When I want to add a new Course I want to be able to add all it's project types in the CourseProjectTable, I have this code

```
[BindProperty]
    public Course Course { get; set; }
    public List<ProjectType> typesList { get; set; }
    public CourseProjectType proType { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        var data = (from typesList in _Context.ProjectType select typesList).ToList();
        typesList = data;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        var course = Course;
        var typeslist = typesList;

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }
        if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Course>(
            course, "type",   // Prefix for form value.
            s => s.CourseName))
        {
            _Context.Course.Add(course);
            await _Context.SaveChangesAsync();

            for (int i = 0; i < typeslist.Count(); i++)
            {
                if(typeslist[i].checkboxAnswer == true)
                {
                    proType.CourseId = course.CourseId;
                    proType.ProjectTypeId = typeslist[i].ProjectTypeId;
                    _Context.CourseProjectType.Add(proType);
                }
            }

            await _Context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToPage("./AllCourses");
        }

        return null;

    }
```

and this is it's part of razor page

```
<div class="col-md-9">
            <label asp-for="@Model.typesList">Project Types For this Course:</label>
            @if (Model.typesList != null && Model.typesList.Count() > 0)
             {
                for (int i = 0; i < Model.typesList.Count(); i++)
                {
            <div>
                <input asp-for="@Model.typesList[i].checkboxAnswer" type="checkbox" />
                <label asp-for="@Model.typesList[i].checkboxAnswer">@Model.typesList[i].ProjectTypeName</label>

                @Html.HiddenFor(x => @Model.typesList[i].ProjectTypeId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(y => @Model.typesList[i].ProjectTypeName)
            </div>
                 }
             }
        </div>
```

I am sorry, this is such long question, but when I try to use the typeslist in the OnPostAsync() method I find it to be null even though in OnGet() method it had three items .. I don't know what is the problem and if this the right way to get user input and store it in the database for many to many relationships tables.

Comment: You only have [BindProperty] on the Course object, maybe this is the cause.

Comment: @Iztoksson, Thank You! it's such a silly mistake, but thank you for taking the time to answer.